# How to fix Images path after RewriteRule?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've some page `https://my.site.com/shop/viewbills` and RewriteRule

```
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z]+)/?([a-z]+)$ /?page=$1&$2=$3 [QSA,L]
```

But in this case I can't understand how I can fix uri for images located on this page.

Their path as `src="storage/cache/img/avatars_random/20.jpg"` and it isn't works with this RewriteRule. Looks like new img src path must be `src="../storage/cache/img/avatars_random/20.jpg"` because new uri with this RewriteRule's `https://my.site.com/shop/storage/cache/img/avatars_random/20.jpg`

Comment: Maybe use an absolute path `/shop/storage/cache/img/avatars_random/20.jpg` for the image?

Comment: I've `RewriteRule ^/?([a-z]+)$ /?page=$1 [QSA,DPI]`, so `/shop/` it's `page=shop`, and I haven't path shop at default. default for images `/storage/..`